# A weighted normal-integral is doable?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, normal-distribution, polar-coordinates

Question without words: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-a^2x^2)/(1+x^2)=? \ $. Maple fails on this, but I saw this in a Russian example-book, so I am curious. I can do it for $a=0$ only.

Comment: i found this here $$\pi\,{{\rm e}^{{a}^{2}}}-{\frac {\pi\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}}{{\rm e}^{{a}^{2}
}}{\rm erf} \left(a\right)}{a}}
$$

Comment: I would use Parseval for this one. The result would be something along the lines of @Dr.SonnhardGraubner's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at

$$I(b)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-bx^2)/(1+x^2)dx$$

with $b=a^2$, take the derivative w.r.t. $b$ and you can establish the following equation for $I$

$$\frac{dI(b)}{db}=I(b)-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{b}}$$

you can solve this to arrive at the following representation for $I(b)$:

$$I(b)=\pi e^b - \sqrt{\pi}e^b\int_0^{b}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-t}dt$$

The last integral is [an incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Algebraic_relations) which can be transformed into an erf function via the relation

$$\gamma(\frac{1}{2},b)=\sqrt{\pi}\text{erf}(\sqrt{b})$$

which will get you the expression Dr. Sonnhard Graubner suggested in the comments.

Comment: That is huge! Is the DE separable or exact? I know only these 2 types.

Comment: It's an inexact differential equation, but you can transform it into an exact one with the multiplier $e^{-b}$.